# How to create custom security filter for microservices using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have minimal basic idea of Spring security. I want to develop multiple microservices for an application where I want employ one point authentication and authorization that can be used in all microservices. To make it more specific, I want to create a generic Filter that can only be used in web.xml of every microservice applications. I do not want to use the followings in all microservices.

## spring-security.xml

```
<http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/customaccessdenied.jsp" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/manage*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login default-target-url="/index" always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <logout/>
        <!-- <remember-me/> -->
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="deb" password="deb" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>



web.xml
=======
<!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I do not want to use the above in all microservices. My application should look like below the image.

[image]

Please help me how to achieve it, if you have any sample application, please provide me link. Again the whole point is to place all security related stuff in one place and use that library and custom filter only web.xml of all micro services.

I want to achieve like this

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>mySecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.world.india.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>mySecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Please I need your help in this regard. Hope it will be helpful for others.

Comment: To me **"I want to create a generic Filter that can only be used in web.xml of every microservice applications. I do not want to use the followings in all microservices"** sounds like a contradiction. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: You need a separate service for authentication so that all unauthorized request can be directed to it which can expose either REST API or LogIn page. All other micro services and Web App should only allow authorized request only. This you can set in configuration file. This way all your authorization related code will reside in single module.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place all the views in folder and set access to certain role. 
So any request with /service/* can redirect to a login screen while all other might not require authentication (/*)

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
    <http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/service/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/customaccessdenied.jsp" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/manage*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login default-target-url="/index" always-use-default-     target="true"/>
    <logout/>
    <!-- <remember-me/> -->
</http>
```

YOu can set up your custom security configuration following this [tutorial](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're asking: from your image it appears all microservices will reside in the same web application, configured from the same web.xml, but your code snippet indicates that your microservices will reside in separate web applications, which would indeed make total sense.

Either way: just add a root application context in your web.xml, where you specify the security configuration:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/common-security-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The `common-security-config.xml` will be the base application context for ALL child application contexts in the same web application (in your case: all the microservices etc). Place your Spring Security configuration there and you should be all right.

If all of your microservices reside in the same web application, this is all you need to do; if not, just create a common module that includes the security configuration (in `src/main/resources`) and any supporting classes that might be needed for security configuration. Add a reference to that module and add the common configuration in the web.xml of all microservice modules.

Please note that either way, if you want to use method-level security (using e.g. `@Secured`) this configuration will need to be included in the configuration for each child microservice.

Answer (score 0):

In its essence your question sounds like you want to have a re-usable spring security java configuration (instead of a spring-security.xml). If so, you can either create a custom security dependency or go for security-as-a-service.

**Dependency**: Place your security implementation in a jar (E.g. the com.world.india.DelegatingFilterProxy), and add this jar as a dependency to each of your services. This way all your security changes are isolated to a different module and anytime you upgrade the security, the only change to other micro-services is the dependency version.

**Service**: Deploy your security application too as a service. Now, the problem is reduced to establishing a secure handshake between two of your own services (i.e. the security micro-service and other micro-services). Using this approach, the upgrades to your security services are seamless and transparent (if you are using a service-discovery mechanism) to the other services (e.g. the A-MicroService) consuming it.

For hints on a non-XML based configuration, check this answer: [Configure Spring Security without XML in Spring 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961600/configure-spring-security-without-xml-in-spring-4)